# does user defined callback function uses thread pool in node.js?

Tags: node.js

This question is to understand how event loop calls thread pool to process task.
Say,
I want to create a function (say to process small task) not any i/o operation, i want that to process using a callback function, so that it can call thread pool and task can be concurrent with my main thread, and return result in callback after completion. I have understanding that it can be done by creating child processes(forking etc),
but, I am little confused and want to understand how exactly is process executes concurrently in single threaded node in i/o operation and not in user defined operation. What exactly happens in event loop, will all event be passed to thread pool or how it identifies if it is I/O operation??

I am new at node.js and totally confused.
Help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> “Node.js manages its own threads for I/O” by using libuv for operations involving the network, file system, etc. libuv essentially creates a thread pool for I/O that varies in size based on platform. The V8 event loop is a separate thread that processes events in the queue. Those events map to a JavaScript function to execute with the event data. This is how asynchronous I/O is handled by Node.js.

***Source:*** http://www.wintellect.com/blogs/dbanister/stop-fighting-node.js-in-the-enterprise

So each I/O operation executes outside V8 event loop thread, that's why it runs concurrently.

I/O operations run efficiently because, as you mentioned, a thread pool is used - a group of threads that "wait" for incoming tasks from V8 event loop, execute them, and return data to JavaScript callback functions.

Comment: if i create 2 function say A and B, i call A sending function B as parameter and function A called that function as callback, will this function be listed in event loop??? Now execution of this region of code is asynchronous or synchronous??

Comment: @SureshMainali It is synchronous i.e. functions A and B run within the same iteration of event loop. To make B run in another iteration you may use something like `setTimeout` or [`process.nextTick`](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_nexttick_callback)

Comment: @SureshMainali rephrasing my comment: this region of code ***might*** be asynchronous if you call B from within another asynchronous function (e.g. `setTimeout`, `process.nextTick`, `fs.readFile`, etc.)

Comment: @SureshMainali You're welcome:) I have to add that in spite of function B is async when using `setTimeout`, it still runs in the same thread as function A (V8 event loop thread). Only I/O operations and [native modules](http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html) can be executed in a thread other than V8 event loop thread.

Comment: thanks, for quick response. I have some follow up question, please not feel irritated as i am new in node and with full of curiosity :) 

SO, Is is correct if i understand that for operations like setTimeout, process.nextTick which do not need any I/O operation executes in state
main->eventloop->main right? not going to thread pool.

and what about setInterval function? does this also execute in same thread or??

Comment: @SureshMainali it's OK :) yes, you're right. `process.nextTick`, `setTimeout`, and `setInterval` not going to thread pool and execute in main V8 thread even though they are all async.

Answer (score -1):

As you already stated Node runtime is single threaded.
Node is well suited for IO bound operation. It's less recommended for CPU bound because it will block Node's event loop.

- If you really want to do CPU bound work async with node you can achieve that using a nodes cluster but you'll have to manage the communication between them. (A simple example here - http://davidherron.com/blog/2014-07-03/easily-offload-your-cpu-intensive-nodejs-code-simple-express-based-rest-server) or using chiled process - http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

Comment: So, can i understand that, asynchronous property of node is only for I/O task, remaining is synchronous??? in normal sense...

Comment: @SureshMainali, exactly. That's why node is awesome for the web, because it's mostly IO (handle web req/web resp/db/disk). But definitely not for CPU intensive tasks.